# Need to calculate median for dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have following data:

```
                                            nmins
mac                 status  
3899255688923906615 problems_group_group    198
                     problems_individual    162
3929325397689943966 problems_group_group    198
                     problems_individual    117
4613397785779760382 problems_group_group    198
                     problems_individual    5
4861652328118504220 problems_group_group    198
                     problems_individual    1078
5035225657878165368 problems_group_group    198
                     problems_individual    140
9405388597739161436 problems_group_group    98
                     problems_individual    83
10100515225827442540 problems_group_group   198
                     problems_individual    106
11478610956449410394 problems_group_group   198
                     problems_individual    103
```

DataFrame has following structure:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 16 entries, (3899255688923906615, problems_group_group) to (11478610956449410394, problems_individual)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
nmins    16 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 375.0+ bytes
```

I need to the ratio 'problems_individual/problems_group_group' for every mac and calculate median for whole dataframe. The field 'problems_group_group' may be equal to 0 - such cases I don't need to include to calculations...
I have tried to use something like df.groupby('mac').transform() but need not have success...
Please explain me how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found out how to fix it:

```
xx = df.groupby('mac').apply(lambda o : 0 if (o.nmins[0] == 0) else o.nmins[1]/o.nmins[0])

xx[xx != 0].median()
```

Comment: ..then also explain it in more detail so all can learn from it instead of a code dump only.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let us create a dataframe similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [np.random.randint(10_000, 20_000, 100).astype(str), ["group", "individual"]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names = ["address", "status"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"nmins" : np.random.randint(0, 200, len(index))}, index = index)
```

Which looks something like this :

```
                    nmins
address status
16541   group         173
        individual     67
11304   group          70
        individual    133
15086   group          69
...                   ...
10851   individual    178
14781   group         173
        individual    186
12667   group          93
        individual     44
```

Now we can use `pd.IndexSlice` to work some magic,

we will separate the different groups with the slice like that :

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
individual = df.loc[idx[:, "individual"], "nmins"].values
group =  df.loc[idx[:, "group"], "nmins"].values
```

Finally, we call the conditions with `numpy where` : the following code says that if the `nmins` column, at the `group` index, is not equal to zero then do `individual/group` in a safely manner and `0` otherwise.

```
xx = np.where(df.loc[idx[:,"group"], "nmins"].ne(0), 
              np.divide(individual,group, where = group!=0),
                                                         0)
```

Then you can find the median with as you did :

```
np.median(xx[xx!0])
```

In this case it might be a bit more work conceptually but it would be vastly more efficient on larger dataframes and it also helps to think about [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) properly.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

Using @NaturalFrequency setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [np.random.randint(10_000, 20_000, 100).astype(str), ["group", "individual"]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names = ["address", "status"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"nmins" : np.random.randint(0, 200, len(index))}, index = index)

df_out = df.median(level=1).T.eval('ratio = individual / group')
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
status  group  individual     ratio
nmins      97          99  1.020619
```